# How to add a running count to rows in a 'streak' of consecutive days

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, date-arithmetic, gaps-and-islands

Thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-cat-recall) for the suggestion to add the create/insert statements.

```
create table test (
  pid integer not null,
  date date not null,
  primary key (pid, date)
);

insert into test values
  (1,'2014-10-1')
, (1,'2014-10-2')
, (1,'2014-10-3')
, (1,'2014-10-5')
, (1,'2014-10-7')
, (2,'2014-10-1')
, (2,'2014-10-2')
, (2,'2014-10-3')
, (2,'2014-10-5')
, (2,'2014-10-7');
```

I want to add a new column that is 'days in current streak'
so the *result* would look like:

```
pid    | date      | in_streak
-------|-----------|----------
1      | 2014-10-1 | 1
1      | 2014-10-2 | 2
1      | 2014-10-3 | 3
1      | 2014-10-5 | 1
1      | 2014-10-7 | 1
2      | 2014-10-2 | 1
2      | 2014-10-3 | 2
2      | 2014-10-4 | 3
2      | 2014-10-6 | 1
```

I've been trying to use the answers from

- [PostgreSQL: find number of consecutive days up until now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794074/postgresql-find-number-of-consecutive-days-up-until-now)
- [Return rows of the latest 'streak' of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004328/return-rows-of-the-latest-streak-of-data-from-using-postgresql)

but I can't work out how to use the `dense_rank()` trick with other window functions to get the right result.

Comment: You said, "pid is unique, date isn't." But your data says date is unique, and pid isn't. Which is right?

Comment: Date isn't unique in the sense that multiple pid's can have the same date. I'll make the question clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on this table (not using the [SQL keyword "date"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as column name.):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  pid int
, the_date date
, PRIMARY KEY (pid, the_date)
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT pid, the_date
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pid, grp ORDER BY the_date) AS in_streak
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , the_date - '2000-01-01'::date
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY the_date) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
) sub
ORDER  BY pid, the_date;
```

Subtracting a `date` from another `date` yields an `integer`. Since you are looking for consecutive days, every next row would be greater by *one*. If we subtract `row_number()` from that, the whole streak ends up in the same group (`grp`) per `pid`. Then it's simple to deal out number per group.

`grp` is calculated with two subtractions, which should be fastest. An equally fast alternative could be:

```
the_date - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY the_date) * interval '1d' AS grp
```

One multiplication, one subtraction. String concatenation and casting is more expensive. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Don't forget to partition by `pid` additionally in *both* steps, or you'll inadvertently mix groups that should be separated.

Using a subquery, since that is typically faster than a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). There is nothing here that a plain subquery couldn't do.

And since you mentioned it: `dense_rank()` is obviously *not* necessary here. Basic [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) does the job.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get more attention if you include CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT statements in your question.

```
create table test (
  pid integer not null,
  date date not null,
  primary key (pid, date)
);

insert into test values
(1,'2014-10-1'), (1,'2014-10-2'), (1,'2014-10-3'), (1,'2014-10-5'),
(1,'2014-10-7'), (2,'2014-10-1'), (2,'2014-10-2'), (2,'2014-10-3'),
(2,'2014-10-5'), (2,'2014-10-7');
```

The principle is simple. A streak of distinct, consecutive dates minus row_number() is a constant. You can group by the constant, and take the dense_rank() over that result.

```
with grouped_dates as (
  select pid, date, 
         (date - (row_number() over (partition by pid order by date) || ' days')::interval)::date as grouping_date
  from test
)
select * , dense_rank() over (partition by grouping_date order by date) as in_streak
from grouped_dates
order by pid, date
```

```
pid  date         grouping_date  in_streak
--
1    2014-10-01   2014-09-30     1
1    2014-10-02   2014-09-30     2
1    2014-10-03   2014-09-30     3
1    2014-10-05   2014-10-01     1
1    2014-10-07   2014-10-02     1
2    2014-10-01   2014-09-30     1
2    2014-10-02   2014-09-30     2
2    2014-10-03   2014-09-30     3
2    2014-10-05   2014-10-01     1
2    2014-10-07   2014-10-02     1
```

Comment: When I run this I don't get the break in the first pid group, i.e. the streak continues. When I add the extra pid partition in the second select, as suggested by Erwin, it works as expect.